# Including c++ header files in Xcode without adding the compile source

Tags: c++, xcode, libraries

I'm working to create my own c++ library. I've noticed that I have to add my source file to `Compile Sources` under `Build Phases` in Xcode if I include the header file. Obviously, I don't have to go find every `Boost` or `Curl` file that I use when including one of those header files.

Currently, my "library" consists of a few header file and source files in the same folder. I have added the path to find the header files to `header search paths`.

What's the difference between what I'm writing and the standard libraries that only need header file references?

Comment: I don't understand your question; the difference between what?

Comment: xcode, because it's made by apple, prefers that you use frameworks, for which it helpfully show header files. Apple obviously don't realise that for anyone developing cross-platform code (almost everyone!), this can be horribly inconvenient.

Comment: Your comment leads me to believe that at least I'm doing it correctly with the tools I have.